# Tomcat 7 is ignoring logging.properties

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I recently upgraded my Win 8 development box and my CentOS 6 deployment environment to Tomcat 7.0.42. Started getting the "INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs ..." message. According to other SO questions, the course of action is to enable FINE logging in Tomcat's logging.properties to figure out which JARs are the problem.

I have tried to no avail. No matter what I do, I can't get Tomcat to pay any attention to any changes I make to  ${TOMCAT_HOME)/conf/logging.properties. I have uncommented `org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE` and changed `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level` to FINE. I have set `1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix` to "catalinaish", and even deleted logging.properties altogether. None of these actions have changed what is logged to catalina.out. On either Win 8 or CentOS 6.

I know it's operator error, but I'm not sure what my error is. On the Win 8 box, the behaviour is altered regardless of whether I start Tomcat using "Monitor Tomcat", or whether I use my ant script:

```
    <java classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" failonerror="true" fork="true">
        <classpath path="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/bootstrap.jar:${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/logging.properties" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${env.TOMCAT_HOME}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.base=${env.TOMCAT_HOME}" />
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.io.tmpdir=${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/temp" />
        <!-- Set the required command line arguments -->
        <arg line="start" />
    </java>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat 8 enable debug logging to list unneeded jars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821865/tomcat-8-enable-debug-logging-to-list-unneeded-jars)

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed like how you are starting tomcat? Are you using the ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/startup.sh in CentOS6? Are you sure you are looking for logs at the same location where *FileHandler.directory properties in logging.properties point to? You want to check if CATALINA_BASE environment variable is being set somewhere. It's better to output the environment variable CATALINA_BASE and the value of the java system property catalina.base. You also want to check whether something is being set in ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh

Comment: On CentOS, Tomcat is being started as service. It's all setup automatically by my host's VM template. As far as I can see, it doesn't use startup.sh, but uses the wrapper service instead. I think I'm looking at the right log file - the catalina.out is being written to, for example, when I start and stop the server. setenv.sh does not exist.

Comment: And on the Windows box, I start/stop the server using my ant script, or using the Monitor Tomcat application.

Comment: The Tomcat zip/targz doesn't come with a service script. Did you install tomcat on centos using the tomcat rpm from CentOS repo? If so you probably installed the hundreds of other rpm dependencies along with it. It's not at all a good idea to install tomcat rpm on production environments. It's bad packaging and an example of shoehorning jars into an rpm. I went to the extent of repackaging the tomcat targz as an rpm. I highly recommend the tomcat targz/zip for production environments

Comment: I wasn't clear in my earlier comment - I didn't install Tomcat 7. The VM from my cloud hosting service comes with Tomcat 7 pre-installed. I don't think it's the problem anyway because I have the same problems with logging.properties under Win 8. I'm pretty sure that I'm the problem, I just don't know in what way.